# How to synchronize two ListViews in Delphi?

Tags: listview, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

I'm working on an app for android using Delphi XE8 and I need to synchronize two list views, so that when one is scrolled, the other scrolls in sync. And vice versa. The two lists have the same number of items.

How can I do this?

Comment: It's medium difficult.  Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: On a scale of 1 to 10, it's a high 2/low 3. Does that help?

Comment: I think I was not very specific in my question. I'm actually talking about scrolling, when rolling one, the other has to roll along. Recalling that both have the same number of items.

Comment: procedure TForm1.ListView1ScrollViewChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
 Listview2.ScrollViewPos := Listview1.ScrollViewPos;
end;

Answer (score 4):

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1ScrollViewChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Listview2.ScrollViewPos := Listview1.ScrollViewPos;
end;
```

Comment: I think it would be beneficial for readers with earlier (than XE 8) versions if you mention that the `OnScrollViewChange` event was introduced in XE 8.